# using the jquery animate() api and can't get it to stop bouncing

Tags: jquery

Current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#go').hover(
        function(){ // Change the input image's source when we "roll on"
            $(this).animate({"top": "-=100px"}, 50, "linear", function(){
              $(this).animate({"top": "+=100px"}, 50);
            });
            $(this).attr({ src : '/gfx/go_over.png'});
        }          
    );
});
```

basically I wanted my button to bounce up and change state, then when it comes back down it would stay on that changed state. On rollover I want the reverse to happen.

Im not sure what I'm doing here since everytime it comes down it hovers and bounces again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a single function to [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) it will be executed on the `mouseenter` *and* `mouseleave` events, if you just want it to happen once when moving over the element, use [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) directly, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#go').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({"top": "-=100px"}, 50, "linear", function(){
      $(this).animate({"top": "+=100px"}, 50);
    });
    $(this).attr({ src : '/gfx/go_over.png'});
  });
});
```

Comment: this gives me the same result because once it comes back down it is a mouseenter again

Comment: @Adam - Is it possible for you to wrap it in another element that you're actually hovering, so you don't get mouse issues?  The alternative would be as the first like of the `mouseenter` handler do `if($(this).is(':animated')) return;`